# check_library_exists not works as it should

Tags: cmake

In CMakeLists.txt I write:

```
INCLUDE(CheckLibraryExists)
check_library_exists("libcurl" "" "" HAVE_CURL)
```

HAVE_CURL is always false, even if libcurl installed, and this function not causes fatal errors.

Comment: Have you tried investigating *why* the check fails?

Answer (score 2):

To check why a a try-compile fails, you can run CMake with the `--debug-trycompile` option, which will leave behind the buildsystem for the last `try_compile` command (these are used internally by all the `Check...` modules).

I didn't run the check, but I looked at the code of `CheckLibraryExists`, and it is apparently mandatory to specify a function to look for in that library (the second argument to `check_library_exists`).